# Add an alias for a subquery that I can reference in the main WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create an alias for a subquery so I can reference in the WHERE clause from the main query but it keeps throwing me error telling me that the column doesn't exist.

```
SELECT x.id_lib, (
            SELECT sg.nom FROM subgenres sg WHERE (x.id_gen = sg.id)
        )as genname, x.id_gen
            FROM subgenres_books x WHERE x.id_lib = 1 and genname LIKE 'Satira'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As zip suggests, you can phrase the query as a simple `join`:

```
SELECT sb.id_lib, s.nom, sb.id_gen
FROM subgenres_books sb JOIN
     subgenres s
     ON s.id_gen = sb.id
WHERE sb.id_lib = 1 and s.nom = 'Satira';
```

However, there seems to be no reason to return the subgenre -- it is constant.  So I'm thinking that an `EXISTS` subquery is appropriate:

```
SELECT sb.id_lib, sb.id_gen
FROM subgenres_books sb 
WHERE sb.id_lib = 1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM subgenres s
              WHERE s.id_gen = sb.id
                    s.nom = 'Satira'
             );
```

Comment: `LIKE` makes is almost, but not quite constant if the pattern can have special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT x.id_lib, x.id_gen, genname.nom
            FROM subgenres_books x inner join
 subgenres genname on x.id_gen = genname.id
WHERE x.id_lib = 1 and genname.nom LIKE 'Satira'
```